# Java RESTful Web Service Tutorial with Eclipse and Jetty

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, rest, jetty

I want to build a RESTful Web Service in Java, deployed using Jetty and developed using Eclipse as IDE.
I was wondering if anyone could post or link me to a beginner tutorial (even a "hello world!" would be good, for starters).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Jersey (JSR-311) implementation for RESTful Web Services has a nice "Getting Started" section:

http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/getting-started.html

Comment: link is dead, try this one: http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/getting-started.html

Comment: fas you are the best! Thanks it worked great for me too. You got the mock server up and running in 5 minutes.

Comment: It changed again. I think the new URL is: https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/getting-started.html

Answer (score 1):

Another website I have found to be very beginner-friendly and contains very detailed explanation from ground-up : http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/REST/article.html